# PHP/FB API/GRAPH - Why am I getting an undefined offset error?

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I dont understand why I get this error:

> Notice:  Undefined offset: 0

Im trying to get a list of a users friends from the FB Graph API using:

```
// get users friends
        $friends_url = "https://graph.facebook.com/".$user_id."/friends?access_token=".$access_token;
        $friends_json = file_get_contents($friends_url);
        $friends_data = json_decode($friends_json, true);       

        for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($friends_data); $i++) {
        $friends = $friends_data[$i];
        echo $friends['name'] . ", ";
        }
```

If you var_dump($friends_data) or print_r($friends_data) you can see that Ive got the array of friends, and that data[0] has a friends info. So why the error?

Comment: Can you post some sample of json data you recieve? There is possibility that the `$freinds_data doesn't have numeric index.

Answer (score 1):

The list is stored in

```
$friends_data['data'][$i]
```

not

```
$friends_data[$i]
```

You should do

```
$friends_data = json_decode($friends_json, true)['data'];   

for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($friends_data); $i++) {
    $friends = $friends_data[$i];
    echo $friends['name'] . ", ";
}
```

Sample data is found at: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/

Comment: Thanks! That didnt quite work, but it helped me get in the right direction and i got it working.

Answer (score 0):

I it possible that `$friends_data` doesn't have numeric index.
Your solution would be to use `foreach`:

```
 foreach ($friends_data as $friends) {
    echo $friends['name'] . ", ";
  }
```

Comment: this works:for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($friends_data,1); $i++) {
     $friends = $friends_data['data'][$i];
     echo $friends['name']."<br />";
  }

Comment: How do I get it to stop at the end of the friends list? It keeps going and starts giving me errors once it gets past the last friend.